# C++ - Ordenar de forma particular pontos de um retângulo em um vetor?

Tags: c++, qt, matemática, classificação, lógica

estou com um projeto em c++ onde devo mapear regiões de uma imagem utilizando o click do mouse. A questão é que devo obter os pontos do mapeamento em uma ordem especifica de armazenamento, como na imagem a abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o meu problema começa no momento de armazenar estes dados, pois criei o seguinte vetor para guardar tais pontos: pfileira = {P1, P2, P3, P4}. O problema é que ao clicar na imagem e obter os pontos, eu só consigo armazena-los na ordem do click, ou seja se eu começar mapeando pelo ponto P3 por exemplo, o vetor ficará armazenado como: pfileira = {P3, P2, P1, P4} ou = {P3, P4, P1, P2}. Existe algum teorema que eu possa utilizar para ordenar meu vetor de armazenamento de forma a se obter a sequencia de pontos na ordem = {P1, P2, P3, P4} no meu vetor de pontos sendo eles selecionados de qualquer ponto? tentei diversar formas utilizando até um valor numérico do módulo de cada ponto, porém não funciona para todos os casos. 
Alguém saberia me ajudar neste problema, caso exista alguma solução? Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solução do seu problema é bem simples. O algoritmo básico é o seguinte:

1. Dados os vértices do polígono, calcule o ponto médio (centro do polígono). Para isso, basta fazer, para cada componente de coordenadas (isto é, para o x e depois para o y) a soma dos valores dos componentes em cada vértice e dividir por 4 (já que são somente 4 vértices).
2. Dado o ponto central, calcule os [vetores](http://www1.univap.br/spilling/F1/05-Vetores.pdf) que vão desse ponto central para cada vértice (veja a referência linkada. Não são vetores no sentido de matrizes na programação, mas vetores no espaço, com direção, sentido e magnitude). O vetor é importante para se obter a direção em que o vértice se encontra "ao redor do polígono".
3. Para cada vetor, calcule o ângulo de inclinação entre esse vetor e o eixo horizontal. Para tal, use o cálculo do [arco-tangente](https://pt.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry/trig-equations-and-identities/inverse-trig-functions/v/inverse-trig-functions-arctan) do valor de y em relação ao valor de x (a ideia é uma simplificação do cálculo do ângulo entre vetores; para saber mais, veja [essa referência](http://mundoeducacao.bol.uol.com.br/matematica/angulo-entre-dois-vetores.htm)). Guarde esses ângulos.
4. Finalmente, ordene a lista de pontos com base no valor de seu ângulo. Como na maioria dos sistemas computacionais as coordenadas se iniciam no canto superior esquerdo (isto é, a coordenada 0,0 fica no no alto à esquerda, com x crescendo para a direita e y crescendo pra baixo) isso significa que os ângulos dos vetores vão variar conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim, os ângulos "crescem" no sentido horário a partir do canto superior esquerdo, de acordo com a ordem que você deseja.

### Exemplo de Código

A sua pergunta tem a tag [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), mas não diz detalhes do sistema operacional ou da plataforma gráfica utilizada. Assim, eu vou fazer um exemplo em [Qt](https://www.qt.io/), que é bem mais simples e direto (ao menos pra mim). Você pode facilmente utilizar ele como base para o que quer que esteja fazendo. No exemplo, a ordem dos pontos não é dada por cliques, mas foi colocada arbitrariamente.

**Arquivo `window.h`**

```
#ifndef WINDOW_H
#define WINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QPoint>
#include <QVector>
#include <QVector2D>

/**
 * Janela para exibição dos dados
 */
class Window : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    /**
     * Construtor da classe.
     * @param oVertices Objeto QVector com as coordenadas dos vértices do polígono.
     * @param oVectors Objeto QVector com os vetores do centro a cada vértice do polígono.
     * @param oNames Objeto QVector com os nomes dos vértices (para exibição apenas).
     * @param oCenter Objeto QPoint com as coordenadas do centro do polígono.
     * @param pParent Objeto QWidget que será pai deste objeto criado. O default é 0 (NULL).
     */
    explicit Window(QVector<QPoint> oVertices, QVector<QVector2D> oVectors, QVector<QString> oNames, QPoint oCenter, QWidget *pParent = 0);

protected:

    /**
     * Sobrecarga do evento de pintura, para desenhar o polígono.
     * @param pEvent Instancia de QPaintEvent com os dados do evento.
     */
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pEvent) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

private:

    /** Coordenadas dos vértices do polígono. */
    QVector<QPoint> m_oVertices;

    /** Vetores do centro para cada vértice do polígono. */
    QVector<QVector2D> m_oVectors;

    /** Nomes dos vértices do polígono. */
    QVector<QString> m_oNames;

    /** Coordenadas do centro do polígono. */
    QPoint m_oCenter;
};

#endif // WINDOW_H
```

**Arquivo `window.cpp`**

```
#include "window.h"
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPen>
#include <QPolygon>
#include <QtMath>

//-------------------------------------
Window::Window(QVector<QPoint> oVertices, QVector<QVector2D> oVectors, QVector<QString> oNames, QPoint oCenter, QWidget *pParent): QWidget(pParent)
{
    m_oVertices = oVertices;
    m_oVectors = oVectors;
    m_oNames = oNames;
    m_oCenter = oCenter;

    setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Base);
}

//-------------------------------------
void Window::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pEvent)
{
    QPainter oPainter(this);
    oPainter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);

    int iFontHeight = oPainter.fontMetrics().height();

    QPen oNamePen; // Caneta para desenho dos nomes dos vértices
    oNamePen.setColor(QColor(0, 0, 0, 255)); // Preto
    oNamePen.setWidth(3);

    QPen oPolyPen; // Caneta para desenho do polígono formado pelos vértices
    oPolyPen.setColor(QColor(181, 230, 29, 255)); // Mesma cor da postagem no SOPT :)
    oPolyPen.setWidth(3);

    QPen oVertexPen; // Caneta para desenho dos pontos (em vértices e no centro)
    oVertexPen.setColor(QColor(255, 0, 0, 255)); // Vermelho
    oVertexPen.setWidth(8);

    QPen oVectorPen; // Caneta para desenho dos vetores
    oVectorPen.setColor(QColor(0, 0, 255, 255)); // Amarelo
    oVectorPen.setWidth(1);
    oVectorPen.setStyle(Qt::DashDotDotLine);

    // Desenha os vetores
    foreach(QVector2D vVector, m_oVectors)
    {
        // "Translada" o vetor "de volta para o centro", de forma a mudar a escala global
        // (origem no 0,0 da janela) para escala local (origem no ponto central)
        vVector = vVector + QVector2D(m_oCenter);

        oPainter.setPen(oVectorPen);
        oPainter.drawLine(m_oCenter, vVector.toPoint());
    }

    // Desenha o ponto médio
    QString sName = QString("C (%2, %3)").arg(m_oCenter.x()).arg(m_oCenter.y());
    oPainter.setPen(oVertexPen);
    oPainter.drawPoint(m_oCenter);
    oPainter.drawText(QPoint(m_oCenter.x(), m_oCenter.y() - iFontHeight), sName);

    // Desenha o polígono
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    QPolygon oPoly;

    for(int i = 0; i < m_oVertices.count(); i++)
    {
        QPoint oVertex = m_oVertices[i];
        QString sName = QString("%1 (%2, %3)").arg(m_oNames[i]).arg(oVertex.x()).arg(oVertex.y());

        QVector2D vVector = m_oVectors[i];
        double dAngle = qAtan2(vVector.y(), vVector.x());
        int iAdjust = dAngle >= 0 ? 1.5 * iFontHeight : -iFontHeight; // Posiciona o rótulo acima ou abaixo, conforme a direção do vetor

        oPainter.setPen(oNamePen);
        oPainter.drawText(QPoint(oVertex.x(), oVertex.y() + iAdjust), sName); // Desenha o nome do vértice
        oPainter.setPen(oVertexPen);
        oPainter.drawPoint(oVertex);

        oPoly.append(oVertex);
        x += oVertex.x();
        y += oVertex.y();
    }
    oPainter.setPen(oPolyPen);
    oPainter.drawPolygon(oPoly); // Desenha as linhas do polígono
}
```

**Arquivo `main.cpp`**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtMath>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPair>
#include "window.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication oApp(argc, argv);

    // Define as coordenadas do polígono
    QVector<QPoint> oVertices;
    QVector<QString> oNames;
    oVertices.append(QPoint(930, 162)); oNames.append("P3");
    oVertices.append(QPoint(867, 47));  oNames.append("P2");
    oVertices.append(QPoint(247, 101)); oNames.append("P1");
    oVertices.append(QPoint(267, 238)); oNames.append("P4");

    // Calcula o ponto central (ponto médio) do polígono
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    foreach(QPoint oVertex, oVertices)
    {
        x += oVertex.x();
        y += oVertex.y();
    }
    int iVertices = oVertices.count(); // Número de vértices. No exemplo, é 4.  
    QPoint oCenter(x / iVertices, y / iVertices);

    // Calcula os vetores (do centro a cada vértice) e seus ângulos (em relação eo eixo horizontal)
    QVector<QVector2D> oVectors;
    QVector<double> oAngles;
    foreach(QPoint oVertex, oVertices)
    {
        // Aritmética vetorial, para obter o vetor indo do centro para o vértice
        // Ou, em outras palavras, o vértice tendo como origem o ponto central.
        QVector2D vVector = QVector2D(oVertex) - QVector2D(oCenter);
        oVectors.append(vVector);
    }

    // Exibe o desenho em uma janela
    Window oWindow(oVertices, oVectors, oNames, oCenter);
    oWindow.setFixedSize(1200, 400);
    oWindow.show();

    // Calcula os angulos
    qDebug() << "Angulos e Ordenacao";
    qDebug() << "-------------------";

    // Aqui tem que ser QMultimap, já que a chave são valores numéricos (ângulos) que podem
    // se repetir.
    QMultiMap<double, QPair<QString, QPoint>> mSorted;
    for(int i = 0; i < oVectors.count(); i++)
    {
        QVector2D vVector = oVectors[i];
        QString sName = oNames[i];
        QPoint oVertex = oVertices[i];

        // O arco-tangente retorna o ângulo (em radianos) do vetor com base no eixo x
        double dAngle = qAtan2(vVector.y(), vVector.x());

        qDebug("Angulo (em graus) do vetor que vai para [%s] = %3.2f", qPrintable(sName), qRadiansToDegrees(dAngle));
        mSorted.insert(dAngle, QPair<QString, QPoint>(sName, oVertex));
    }
    qDebug() << "-------------------";

    qDebug() << "Ordenacao Antes: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < oVertices.count(); i++)
        qDebug() << oNames[i] << ": (" << oVertices[i].x() << "," << oVertices[i].y() << ")";

    qDebug() << "Ordenacao Depois: ";
    QMultiMap<double, QPair<QString, QPoint>>::const_iterator it;
    for(it = mSorted.cbegin(); it != mSorted.cend(); ++it)
        qDebug() << it.value().first << ": (" << it.value().second.x() << "," << it.value().second.y() << ")";

    qDebug() << "-------------------";

    return oApp.exec();
}
```

Esse programa gera a seguinte janela (com os vértices e o centro desenhados em vermelho, o polígono em linhas sólidas verdes, e os vetores em linhas pontilhadas azuis):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E imprime a seguinte saída de texto:

```
Angulos e Ordenacao
-------------------
Angulo (em graus) do vetor que vai para [P3] = 4.05
Angulo (em graus) do vetor que vai para [P2] = -17.24
Angulo (em graus) do vetor que vai para [P1] = -173.77
Angulo (em graus) do vetor que vai para [P4] = 161.95
-------------------
Ordenacao Antes: 
"P3" : ( 930 , 162 )
"P2" : ( 867 , 47 )
"P1" : ( 247 , 101 )
"P4" : ( 267 , 238 )
Ordenacao Depois: 
"P1" : ( 247 , 101 )
"P2" : ( 867 , 47 )
"P3" : ( 930 , 162 )
"P4" : ( 267 , 238 )
-------------------
```

Comment: Luiz, eu posso estar super simplificando, mas pensando em quatro pontos `(x,y)` não bastaria comparar as posições entre eles? Ex: O com menor `X` e um `Y` mais alto é o `P1`,  o com `X` baixo e `Y` baixo é  o `P4` e assim por diante?

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly É uma simplificação, claro, mas pode ser bem útil se as formas do AP forem *apenas* retângulos. Sugiro que você mesmo adicione uma resposta com essa ideia (e certamente vai ganhar o meu +1). :)

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Aliás, a minha própria resposta também não é completa. Ela funciona para diferentes polígonos, *desde que eles sejam convexos*. Nos polígonos não-convexos (aqueles com um ou mais vértices "para dentro" do polígono) o ponto médio não está necessariamente dentro do polígono, e assim eles requerem uma solução mais complexa (talvez iniciando no ponto mais no canto superior esquerdo e "seguindo" as arestas).

Comment: Olá @LuizVieira , cara muito obrigado mesmoo, seu código funcionou perfeitamente, também estou utilizando qt para o meu projeto. Testei todos os casos problemáticos pelo seu vetor QHash e todos orderam perfeitamente. Eu tinha medo de ter que entrar em uma análise matemática mais profunda, mas nao teve jeito. Confesso que nao compreendi muito bem todas as funções de Qt que voce utilizou, mas entendi a lógica do ponto médio e da angulação. vou estudar o seu código para usar como base para esta parte estou implementando. Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Achei interessante essa QHash, pois nao tinha conhecimento deste tipo de array antes. vou estudá-lo e utilizá-lo com mais frequencia. Novamente, Obrigado!

Comment: @LuizVieira Só tenho uma dúvida, o vetor QHash, a ordenação está sendo referenciada pelo indice entre [" "]? se fosse um vetor de objetos convencional com os valores setados arbitrariamente essa logica funcionaria?

Comment: Por nada. Só cuidado que o `QHash` não garante ordem (isto é, a ordem de inserção não é mantida). Eu tinha usado ele na primeira versão, mas desisti e usei `QVector` distintos mesmo. Senão o polígono não é sempre desenhado de forma correta (porque a ordem vai ser arbitrária). Eu poderia ter usado `QMap` (que, diferentemente do `QHash`, garante a ordem), mas ele já ordena os dados (tal como o `QMultimap`), e assim o exercício não iria ser útil (porque ao inserir já estaria ordenado pelo nome). rs

Comment: Acabei de responder. Se vc tinha pego o código antes, pegue ele novamente. Eu atualizei ele depois e não usa mais `QHash`. Mas, sim, a ideia é que um hash (ou mapa) permite indexar itens por uma chave (key). :) Para saber mais: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabela_de_dispers%C3%A3o

Comment: Ah, na versão final, quem ordena *de fato* é o `QMultimap`. As chaves são os ângulos, e ele já guarda ordenado. Por isso não precisa executar nenhuma função de ordenação.

Comment: @LuizVieira, me deparei com algumas situações onde sua resposta nao funciona corretamente, gostaria de poder aprofundar melhor este exemplo, saberia como poderiamos proceder com este tópico? eu teria que abrir uma outra pergunta? grato desde já.

Comment: Oi Yuri. Prepare e forneça um exemplo de pontos em que a resposta não funciona, que aí eu consigo avaliar se há um erro nela ou se o problema é outro.